# Find how many children you have of a certain type?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, oop

I have a canvas where I will add some rectangles onto. I want to know how many children of only rectangles I have. A lot like `array.length`.

I have tried this code but have had no luck

```
int count = plain.Children.OfType<Rectangle>.Count;
```

`Plain` is the name of the `Canvas`.

But get the error:

> 'Queryable.OfType(IQuerable)' is a method, which is not valid
>   in the given context. code CS0119.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parentheses when calling [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) and `Count` methods:

```
int count = plain.Children.OfType<Rectangle>().Count();
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly now.